# Basic notation in lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have started learning lambda calculus from the book by Hindley and Seldin.

It brought up the concept with the function $x-y$, first as a function of $x$ and then as a function of $y$. In a way, it emphasized the difference between treating the expression as a function of $x$ and function of $y$, giving separate names to the functions.

$$f(x,y) =  x-y \qquad\text{and}\qquad g(y,x) = x -y$$
and, in $\lambda$ notion,
$$h = \lambda xy.x-y \qquad\text{and}\qquad g = \lambda yx. x-y\,.$$

If I am not wrong then it can be inferred that $f =\lambda x .(x-y)$ means that while computing the value of the expression the expression will vary only with  $x$ and similarly when $\lambda$ is placed with $x$ the other variable $y$ will be kept as a constant.

But then it said that this can be denoted as, with $h$ being the common name of the function
$$h = \lambda xy.(x-y)\qquad\text{and}\qquad h = \lambda yx.(x-y)\,.$$
Is it so that in the above expression the variable which is adjacent to $\lambda$ receives the value and the other one is constant?
The above function is called a two-place function; what does that mean?

Then he introduces the following function in $\lambda$ notation calling it a one-point function:
$$h^\star = \lambda x .(\lambda y . x−y)$$
and says that, for each number $a$, we have $h^\star(a)=\lambda y . a−y$.
Here $a$ is being provided as an argument but $\lambda$ is placed near $y$. Why is this?

And then it deduces that $(h^\star(a))(b)=(\lambda y . a−y)(b) = a−b = h(a,b)$ and says $h^\star$ can be viewed as "representing" $h$. Is "representing" a technical term? How was  $(\lambda y . a−y)(b) = a−b$ concluded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I am not wrong then it can be inferred that :
>
> $f=\lambda x.(x−y)$ means that while computing the value of the expression the
>   expression will vary only with "x" and similarly when "lambda " is
>   placed with x the other variable y" will be kept as a constant .

Yes, intuitively that's how it works.

---

What you're looking is called [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) and it's explained fairly early in this book (in fact, I think it's the next section but I don't have a copy now to check). So when we want to work with functions with many arguments we often do it like this:

$$ f(x,y,z) = x\times y + z$$

But you can break this into simpler functions, $(x \times y)$ and $(+z)$. The multiplication can be broken into even simpler terms, first I provide $x$, then just multiply by $y$, that is, $f^{\star}(y) = x\times y$.

Defining some 1-argument functions:

$$
\begin{align*}
plus_z &:= f^\prime(s) = s + z\\
 times_y &:= f^\star(s) = s\times y
\end{align*}
$$

Combining these we can rewrite $f$ as:

$$ f(x,y,z) = f^\prime(f^\star(x)) = plus_z (times_y ~ x) $$

Writing this in using $\lambda$ we have:

$$ \lambda x y z. (x\times y + z)  \equiv \lambda x.\bigg(\lambda y. \Big(\lambda z. (x\times y + z ) \Big) \bigg)$$

What the author has shown is that you can take a function with many arguments and transform it into many simpler functions with just one argument, the bigger function is just a composition of the simpler ones.

So just how the proof works? In your book the following functions are defined:

$$
\begin{align*}
h^\star &= \lambda x . (\lambda y . x − y)\\
h(x,y) &= x-y
\end{align*}
$$

You want to show that $ h^\star = h$. To do that just take any two arguments $a$ and $b$. First evaluate $h^\star$ in $a$.

$$ h^\star(a) = (\lambda x. (\lambda y. x - y))(a) = \lambda y. a - y$$

This gives you a simpler one argument function $h^\prime = h^\star(a)$.

> How was $(λy.a−y)(b)=a−b$ concluded

The same way $(\lambda x. (\lambda y. x - y))(a) = \lambda y. a - y$ was concluded. Just evaluate the function in $b$.

$$ h^\prime(b) = (h^\star(a))(b) = (\lambda y. a - y)(b) = a - b$$

Which is the same result computed by $h(a,b) = a - b$.

Comment: How in the last line h*(a)(b) = a-b concluded ? Could you elaborate this part ?

Comment: Sorry ..no .. how is (lambda*y .a  -y)(b) = a -b ...?Any distribution rule ?

Comment: Beware, this is not a times (multiplication), it's like 'plugging' values in a function argument, so for now think it's something like a textual substitution. The argument is $y$ and the function is $a - y$, so $b$ applied to $\lambda y. a - y$ yields $a-b$ .

Comment: Not a times ? Even with textual substitution I cannot conclude how the last expression came out to be "a-b".

Comment: @AgniveshSingh Btw, if this answer is still not useful to you I can change it to address your problem.

Comment: Sorry for late reply , Truly it's a great gesture on your part . If you may please , I would like to understand the last part to be explained a little bit . Actually , I am seeing your comment again and it is becoming a bit clear . So, we write the function in lambda notion and put the value of b there , right ? Still , if you like to explain I am all ears . Thanks a lot .

Comment: Ok, maybe you just need some example. $(\lambda x. x)$  is a function that just returns it's input, so is equivalent to $f(x) = x$, in particular $f(1) = 1$. How do you compute $(\lambda x.x) ~ 1$? Just take any $x$ after the **"."** and substitute by $1$, also the $\lambda x$ disappears because you "consumed" the input, therefore $(\lambda x.x) ~ 1 $ reduces to $1$. So you have $f(y) = a - y$, $f(b) = a - b$. Using lambdas $(\lambda y. a - y) ~ b$ becomes $a - b$ by the same reason above.